# How to share Session between Web Application (Core PHP) and another Web Application (Laravel) on Same Server?

Tags: php, laravel

I have a web application built on Core PHP and there is a need to build complex module which is decided to be build on Laravel 5.7. What I need is without login twice same user should be able to access Core PHP module and Laravel module.

Comment: Do you have current login session in core PHP application?

Comment: very dull idea to share sessions in between two servers, but u can use same session driver for both installations. good luck with the mess.

Comment: Please follow - https://laravel.io/forum/03-18-2015-is-it-possible-to-pass-laravel-5-session-variables-to-external-php and https://laraveldaily.com/how-to-use-external-classes-and-php-files-in-laravel-controller/

Comment: @MihirBhende Please elaborate more, I didn't get it

Comment: What is the entry point where user will login into the application? Will it be core PHP or it will be through Laravel's login page?

Comment: @Leorent I want to share session between two applications on same server and same database residing on same server.

Comment: @MihirBhende User Login with Core PHP Application and from Core PHP app dashboard there is a link to redirect on Laravel application.

Comment: @ManishKumar were you able to find solution?

Answer (score 0):

Laravel allows several session drivers such as `file` or `database`. If both applications share the file location or database table, it could be possible for them to share the session.

More information about drivers can be found in the documentation: https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/session#configuration

FYI: It will not be easy to do this, and sessions are not supposed to work like this. A better way would be to use a central login system.

Comment: the real answer to his question is that he needs to use dedicated stateless authentication server, so both other web servers can authenticate from same resource.

Comment: @Jerodev ok, let me follow this link.